# Python/ Beautiful Soup Data Displaying Issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-scrubbing

I am trying to pull some data from a website. Once I checked the data that I pulled with beuatifulsoup (using print(soup) in the code below) does not seem very well. It is different than once I check with **view-source:URL**. I am unable to find the fields that I am looking for.
Could you please help me to find a solution?

Website: https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/mercury-row-stalvey-contemporary-4725-wide-1-drawer-server-w003245064.html

Basically, I am trying to get price of this product. I used the same code structure on other websites, it worked properly but it is not working on wayfair.

The second thing that I could not find a solution yet is the last line of my code (StyledBox-owpd5f-0 PriceV2__StyledPrice-sc-7ia31j-0 lkFBUo pl-Price-V2 pl-Price-V2--5000). Instead of name of the product is there a way to get only price like $389.99?

Thanks in advance!

This my code:

```
html = requests.get('https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/mercury-row-stalvey-contemporary-4725-wide-1-drawer-server-w003245064.html')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text,"html.parser")
print(soup)
inps=soup.find("div",class_="SFPrice").find_all("input")
for inp in inps:
    print(inp.get("StyledBox-owpd5f-0 PriceV2__StyledPrice-sc-7ia31j-0 lkFBUo pl-Price-V2 pl-Price-V2--5000"))
```

Comment: Have you actually run your code? It should produce an error (as in my tests), because even the first "div" isn't in the requested html data. It's a client-rendered site!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'})[0].getText()
```

Or in a more simple way:

```
inps=soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'})[0]
inps.getText()
```

Both return the price for that specific product.

Comment: Thank you four the quick response. But both of them gives me the error below.

Comment: inps=soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'})[0]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That means there are none. That also explains why your original code didn't return anything. It was actually more correct.

Comment: I did my example using Selenium. With requests i get the same error, and it is due to it being a client side rendered page as the answer below is stating.

Answer (score 0):

Your site example is a **client-side rendered page** and the original html-data fetched doesn't include the searched for elements (like the div with class "SFPrice").

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) for learning about how to scrape javascript-rendered pages with beautifulsoup in combination with **selenium** and **phantomJS**, dryscrape or other options.

Or you could also look at [this guide](https://sadesmith.com/2018/06/15/blog/scraping-client-side-rendered-data-with-python-and-selenium).

Comment: Please post a comment indicating the duplicate rather than posting a non-answer with a link to a different question.

Comment: @tripleee How is it a duplicate, when he wasn't aware of the issue? So this answers his question, why he cannot find the element.

Comment: We can't require those who ask to know the answer. The guidance is that questions with the same *answer* should be closed as duplicates.